# Animate the height of a div depending on content of a Bootstrap tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, height

I'm wondering how I can achieve a specific effect in a site I'm working on.

What I have currently is a section. Within that I have Bootstrap tabs, but rather than the conventional tabs on top, content below, I've opted for tabs on the left, content on the right.

The amount of content in the right content panel will vary and ultimately the height of the section will increase and decrease accordingly. So the tab content has an influence on the height of the section.

Ideally what I'd like to happen is for the height of the section to ease when it changes rather a quick jump between varying heights. I'm unsure whether I would have to bind something to the tabs script or whether it can be done without that.

I've attached a quick mock-up of what I mean.

[image: Tabbed Auto Height Mockup]

Can anybody help out with this? Thanks

**EDIT** Markup below and [JS Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zE9T5/)

```
<section class="tabs" id="project-tabs">

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

    <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">Tab One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Tab Two</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>

</div><!-- /.col-6-->

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="one">
    <p>Lot of content</p>
  </div>


  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="two">
    <p>Less Content</p>
  </div>
</div>



</div><!-- /.col-6-->


</div><!-- /.row-->
</div><!-- /.container-->
</section>


<script>
var section = $("#project-tabs"),
curHeight = section.height(),
autoHeight = section.css('height', 'auto').height();

section.height(curHeight).animate({ height: autoHeight }, 1000, function() {

section.css('height', 'auto'); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you using tabs or stackable pills, is it possible to give some html?

Comment: If you can make a fiddle, we might be able to tweak your code.

Comment: Yes, no problem. Have added markup in edit...and no I'm not using stackable pills

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zE9T5/ as requested too. Note the jump in height on the grey section. Thats the area I want to animate/ease rather than jump

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?